# Simulating touch events with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a button, which when when clicked opens a popup. I'm just triggering that by simulating a click event at the moment, because there is a 3rd party script involved that I can't directly access.

I'm using this code to duplicate events for touch enabled devices:

```
['click', 'touch'].forEach(function(eventType){
  btn.addEventListener(eventType, function(event){
    targetElem.click();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Can't seem to find a .click() equivalent for .touch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent('touchstart'))
```